# Awkward result found on reading CSV file

Tags: android, csv

I want to read CSV file. The problem is when i print a value of 0 or any other index the awkward result shown as you can see on snapshot. Snapshot attached. 
[image: Snapshot]

Read value from this code:

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.stats);
        FileReader csvFile = new FileReader(inputStream);
        List<String[]> scoreList = csvFile.read();

        for(String[] scoreData:scoreList ) {
            Toast.makeText(this, scoreData[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

FileReader class:

```
package com.example.zohaib.ultimatesmsblocker;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileReader {
    InputStream inputStream;

    public FileReader(InputStream inputStream){
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }
    public List<String[]> read(){
        List<String[]> resultList = new ArrayList();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try {
            String csvLine;
            while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] row = csvLine.split(",");
                resultList.add(row);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file: "+ex);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error while closing input stream: "+e);
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

**CSV file:**
[image: CSV]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you're trying to load is not a `CSV`, but a `XLSX`.

Not every Excel file is a `CSV` file. You need to export it to a `CSV` using Excel.

Excel's `.xlsx` files are actually `XML` files in certain format packed in `ZIP`. The `PK` you see as the first two letters represent the `ZIP` header.